# Need help for checksum on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I Had a issue wih a vehicle tracker I purchased from China. The maker only sent me the function below.

Can anyone help me how to make this checksum with python:

```
Checksum (2 byte)*

Unsigned char Checksum (const char *s,int Length)
{
    Unsigned char result;

    result = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<Length;i++)
    {
        result ^=*s++
    }

    return result;
}
```

UPDATE. I got it working with the code below from the accepted answer.

```
chk = reduce(lambda a,b : a^b, [ord(c) for c in s])
```

Comment: The code in your question isn't valid C/C++ (assuming that's what it's supposed to be).

Comment: Try add your code snippet in python - shows the efforts.

Comment: This piece of code came with the GPS tracker I bought on the internet. This is to send a GPRS command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go :

```
s = "test"
chk = reduce(lambda a,b : a^b, [ord(c) for c in s])

print "Checksum : ", chk, " \n"
```

> 

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                         
Checksum :  22
```